# Postgresql - COPY FROM value omitted after 64 characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, debian, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to insert data from a textfile into a Postgres table. However, some data seems to be missing after copying.

**The textfile**:

> TRUE|aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbb|4096|%2Ftest%2F|2013-03-12
>   04:02:15.572433|777|4|2014-06-12 11:47:05.359879

**The SQL query**:

> COPY "table_name" FROM '/tmp/textfile' DELIMITER '|' NULL
>   'None';

**The result**:

[image: not sure]

Input : aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbb

Result: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

What happened to the last 4 characters?

It seems that everything beyond 64 characters gets omitted. I could not find any mention about a buffer of some sorts in the Postgres [COPY documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) so I'm not sure what is going on here. Anyone got an idea?

- OS: Debian 7.4 - 3.2.0-4-686-pae (x86)
- Postgres: 9.1.13

Comment: What is the data type of `filename`? At the image it shows `name` but there is no such type.

Comment: You are right. I made a (stupid) mistake. The column type should have been 'text'. You should post it as an answer and ill accept that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto There is a type called `name`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html
`The name type exists only for the storage of identifiers in the internal system catalogs and is not intended for use by the general user`

Comment: @Igor Ok, that is a type meant for internal use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the data type of the column `filename` to text or varchar(n). Where n is the maximum length of that column